# php CURFILE binary data from database

Tags: php, jira-rest-api, php-curl, remedy

I have data stored in a table that is base64 encoded binary file data. I am migrating this data from a version 7x install of BMC Remedy HelpDesk to Jira Service Desk. I would like to be able to send the binary file data directly to Jira via the attachment api. I really do not want to have to create the file locally on my filesystem first. Is there a way to feed the binary data to PHP's CURLFile?

Here is the example code I am using to post a local file via the api:

```
$process=curl_init($url);
$headers = array(
  'X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck',
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization: Basic XXX'
);

$cfile = new CURLFile("/path/to/file.jpg");
$cfile->setPostFilename("uploaded.jpg");
$data = array('file'=>$cfile);

curl_setopt_array(
  $process,
  array(
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$data,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=> 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=> $headers
  )
);

$result=curl_exec($process);
$ch_error = curl_error($process);
if ($ch_error) {
  print "cURL Error: " . $ch_error;
} else {
  print "\n" . $result . "\n";
}
curl_close($process);
```